# JavaFX FXMLLoader Invalid Property

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I'm looking for a little help with JavaFX 2 using FXML in a Swing context. I built a scene with Scene Builder (Version: 2.0-b10, Changeset: 48fc80a12d33) and am trying to simply load it up into a JFXPanel on a JFrame in Swing under Java 1.7. When I do this I get an Invalid Property error on line 16. This is line 16: `<Label style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Storage Overview Home" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">`

Here is the whole scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="800.0" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <BorderPane layoutX="54.0" layoutY="45.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <left>
                <VBox fx:id="" prefHeight="726.0" prefWidth="210.0" style="-fx-background-color: #dee8f6;">
                    <children>
                        <Label style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Storage Overview Home" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                            <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="18.0" left="6.0" top="6.0" />
                            </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="ASPCombo" prefWidth="150.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="12.0" left="6.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <Label text="Job Information" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="12.0" left="6.0" />
                            </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="activeJobStatusLink" style="-fx-text-fill: #210B61;" text="Active Job Status" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="12.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Hyperlink>
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="jobMonitorThresholdLink" style="-fx-text-fill: #210B61;" text="Job Monitor Threshold History" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="12.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Hyperlink>
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="jobQtempThresholdLink" style="-fx-text-fill: #210B61;" text="Job QTEMP Threshold History" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="12.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Hyperlink>
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="jobSpooledFileThresholdLink" style="-fx-text-fill: #210B61;" text="Job Spooled File Threshold History" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="12.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Hyperlink>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <Label text="See Also">
                            <padding>
                                <Insets bottom="6.0" left="12.0" />
                            </padding>
                        </Label>
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="collectionHistoryLink" style="-fx-text-fill: #210B61;" text="Collection History" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets left="12.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Hyperlink>
                        <Hyperlink fx:id="currentStorageLink" style="-fx-text-fill: #210B61;" text="Current Storage" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="12.0" left="12.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </left>
            <top>
                <ToolBar prefWidth="200.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
                    <items>
                        <Button fx:id="btnRefresh" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Back" />
                        <HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                            <children>
                                <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Refresh" />
                    </items>
                </ToolBar>
            </top>
            <center>
                <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <children>
                        <VBox minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="136.0" prefWidth="766.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                            <children>
                                <Label fx:id="storageOverviewTitle" style="-fx-font-size: 18; -fx-text-fill: #0000FF;" text="Identify and Solve Disk Storage Problems" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                                    <textFill>
                                        <Color blue="1.0" />
                                    </textFill>
                                </Label>
                                <TextArea fx:id="storageOverviewTextArea" editable="false" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="The Storage Overview helps you quickly identify and solve disk storage problems. Most surges in disk use are caused by active jobs. For example, a server communication job can devour a large amount of your unprotected storage space. And, these jobs can be hard to find.  Use the ASP Threshold History and Job Temp Storage History buttons to display the ASPs and jobs that have exceeded their thresholds. Use the Active Jobs Status button to find and hold or end the job(s) causing a disk storage problem." wrapText="true" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                            </children>
                            <VBox.margin>
                                <Insets bottom="24.0" left="24.0" right="24.0" top="24.0" />
                            </VBox.margin>
                        </VBox>
                        <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="177.0" prefWidth="814.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
                            <children>
                                <PieChart fx:id="totalASPUtilizationPieChart" title="Total ASP Utilization" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
                                <PieChart fx:id="utilizationByLibraryPieChart" title="By Library" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
                                <PieChart fx:id="utilizationByIFSDirPieChart" title="By IFS Directory" HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
                        <AreaChart fx:id="ASPUtilizationHistoryAreaChart" title="Utilization History - ASP 001" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <xAxis>
                                <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                            </xAxis>
                            <yAxis>
                                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                            </yAxis>
                        </AreaChart>
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The code I'm using to attempt to display the scene graph is:

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyPanel.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            swingPanel.setScene(scene);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            //Log an error here...
        }
    }
});
```

The error I get is:

```
Invalid property.
/C:/HelpSys/space/trunk/gui/classes/com/helpsystems/space/gui/csi/MyPanel.fxml:16
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.<init>(FXMLLoader.java:1154)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2338)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2311)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
  at com.helpsystems.space.gui.csi.CSIWizzard$1.run(CSIWizzard.java:182)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `padding` property is not a valid property in a `Label` in JavaFX 2.2. In JavaFX 8, `Label` inherits from `Region` (via `Control`) and so inherits the `padding` property. So I suspect SceneBuilder is looking at JavaFX 8 in order to determine the properties.

In JavaFX 2.2 there is a `labelPadding` property which can be set from CSS, so use

```
<Label style="-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-label-padding: 6 0 18 6;" text="Storage Overview Home"
    VBox.vgrow="NEVER">

</Label>
```